# Just spit it out

Tags: riddle, knowledge

> Step 1: Conjugate a letter and a bug.
>   Step 2: Ask for the reason, with another letter.
>   Step 3: Pull the rest out of your shoe.
>   Step 4: Ignore the sea and replase it.

Extra tips below

> The title will show you the answer.

Comment: is the word 'replase' intentional?

Comment: @KevinL I have the right to remain silent.

Comment: hmm .... I'll take that as a yes  :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you

> AMYLASE?

Step 1: Conjugate a letter and a bug.

> Conjugating Be (B/Bee) gives you AM.

Step 2: Ask for the reason, with another letter.

> As @nikki found, you need to ask Y (why).

Step 3: Pull the rest out of your shoe.

> As @nikki found, the shoe part is your LACE.

Step 4: Ignore the sea and replase it.

> We need to ignore the C and replace it with an S, giving LASE.

Putting this all together we get

> AM + Y + LASE = AMYLASE, an enzyme found in saliva (hence the title Spit it Out!)

Comment: Hmmm, was that too easy?

Comment: That wasn't super easy, I had to play around with it and didn't realize what spitting had to do with anything until I found the answer @tox123

Comment: Shoot! I did not realise the rot 13(or = NZ) part!

Comment: @nikki I think we traded inspirations for our last couple of answers!

Comment: Haha! Looks like we did! :D

Answer (score 8):

Partial answer

Step 1: Conjugate a letter and a bug.

> B (bee)

Step 2: Ask for the reason, with another letter.

> Y (why)

Step 3: Pull the rest out of your shoe.

> Lace?

Step 4: Ignore the sea and replase it.

> Replace 'c' in lace with something?

So the answer is

> bylane?

Comment: Pay more attention to grammer & mechanics.